# When accessing Joomla from an external script when should you include ('libraries/joomla/factory.php');?

Tags: cms, php, external-script

I've been reading up on how to access Joomla from external php scripts and I've noticed that there tends to be 2 flavours of code- external scripts that use `require('libraries/joomla/factory.php');` and those that don't.

factory.php doesn't seem to be necessary, so for what reason(s) would you include it?

EDIT
Here is an example of code that uses factory.php

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on whether you use any `JFactory::` calls, given that it provides useful functions like:

```
getApplication
getConfig
getSession
getLanguage
getDocument
getUser
getCache
getACL
getDbo
getMailer
getFeedParser
getXML
getEditor
getURI
getDate
createConfig
createSession
createDbo
createMailer
createLanguage
createDocument
getStream
```

I can imagine a lot of good reason to use it.

Comment: I read that if you include `require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );` and
`require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );` JFactory would be included.  Is this wrong? Link http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1701888

Comment: Specifically it said "Those two includes import the framework, including JFactory, into the execution path."

Comment: Well `defines` just setups up all the `JPATH_*` globals and `framework` is effectively the whole CMS so no then you wouldn't need JFactory to be included separately.

Comment: I should have included the code when I posted. Anyway I've updated the question. Thanks.